# Permission denied when login to docker hub from AWS linux virtual machine

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, dockerhub, amazon-linux

I'm using AWS Linux virtual machine as my production server. When I try to login to Docker-hub from AWS Linux virtual machine it says permission denied while trying to connect to the docker daemon socket. There are solutions in the internet and those need 'Sudo' access. But I just connect to the VM using SSH with user I created named prod-user. Therefor I don't have password.

[click here tom see the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGvE2.png)

Comment: Are you connecting AWS instance using .pem file?

Comment: Which AMI are you using? Asking this to make sure you have docker installed on the server.

Comment: @SachinArote I connect to the AWS instance with ssh.

Comment: @Pacifist i'm using Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 version. But I already installed docker and docker-compose.

Comment: Add that prod-user in docker group then. Using ```usermod -a -G docker prod-user```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fixed this with the help of @Pacifit answer. Since I cannot do any sudo things as prod-user what I did was I connect to the VM as ec2-user and then I added prod-user to the group by using

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker prod-user
```

and change the permission. Then I was able to execute docker in prod-user.

Comment: This is the same thing I was asking. Didn't you try this when we were talking about it :) ? `$USER=prod-user` or whatever user you want to add. It was a variable.

Comment: No @pacifist. I was using prod-user to logging. So I couldn't able to add to group since permission denied. :-)

Answer (score 7):

It seems the user you are using to access docker hub doesn't have enough permission. You can try adding prod-user to group Docker.

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

`usermod` is a command that modifies the system configuration for a specific user.

`-a` is a shortcut for --append: It means append the group to the list of groups the user belongs to.

`-G` is a shortcut for --groups: It tells usermod that the next argument is a group.

`docker` is the group we want to add $USER to.

`$USER` is the user that we want to modify.

If this alone doesn't resolve the issue then try below :

```
chmod 664 /var/run/docker.sock ## First try this.
chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock ## Then this. Not recommended though due to full permission.
```

Comment: Thanks @Pacifist. But the thing is when I type  "sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER", it required the Password which doesn't exit. I mean sudo password.

Comment: @kavin_Ab did you give a try to increase the permission?

Comment: No. I didn't increase the permissions.

Comment: @kavin_Ab I remember fixing the same issue by increasing the permission. So if you want you can give a try.

Comment: @OpenBSDNinja  exactly!! I forgot to add. But anyway it’s not helping as OP doesn’t have password.

Comment: i still think he needs to reboot. From what I've read it seems he just can't connect to docker. He can follow this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html#install_docker reboot and try run ```docker run -t -i -p 80:80 hello-world``` to test instead of starting out with docker login